# Unsupported Data Type Error

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query with sub queries:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Mtg2012.Employee_ID, Mtg2012.Mtg2012, Mtg2011.Mtg2011, Mgr2011.Mgr2011,     Mgr2012.Mgr2012
FROM  (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Employee_ID, Manager_Readiness_Rating AS Mgr2011
           FROM   dbo.v_sc17_TMS_Data_Career_Meeting_Rating AS v_sc17_TMS_Data_Career_Meeting_Rating_1
           WHERE (Plan_Year = 2011)
           GROUP BY Employee_ID, Manager_Readiness_Rating) AS Mgr2011 FULL OUTER JOIN
               (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Employee_ID, Manager_Readiness_Rating AS Mgr2012
                FROM   dbo.v_sc17_TMS_Data_Career_Meeting_Rating AS v_sc17_TMS_Data_Career_Meeting_Rating_1
                WHERE (Plan_Year = 2012)
                GROUP BY Employee_ID, Manager_Readiness_Rating) AS Mgr2012 ON Mgr2011.Employee_ID = Mgr2012.Employee_ID FULL OUTER JOIN
               (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Employee_ID, Meeting_Readiness_Rating AS Mtg2011
                FROM   dbo.v_sc17_TMS_Data_Career_Meeting_Rating AS v_sc17_TMS_Data_Career_Meeting_Rating_1
                WHERE (Plan_Year = 2011)
                GROUP BY Employee_ID, Meeting_Readiness_Rating) AS Mtg2011 ON Mgr2011.Employee_ID = Mtg2011.Employee_ID FULL OUTER JOIN
               (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Employee_ID, Meeting_Readiness_Rating AS Mtg2012
                FROM   dbo.v_sc17_TMS_Data_Career_Meeting_Rating
                WHERE (Plan_Year = 2012)
                GROUP BY Employee_ID, Meeting_Readiness_Rating) AS Mtg2012 ON Mtg2011.Employee_ID = Mtg2012.Employee_ID
```

When I run this for the last 3 columns I get the UNSUPPORTED DATA TYPE ERROR but for the first one I get the records returned. It doesn't make sense because they are all being built off the same table. Could it be in the joins? I worked on this all night and could not resolve it.

Comment: What datatypes are used for the columns Manager_Readiness_Rating and Meeting_Readiness_Rating in the table (view?) named v_sc17_TMS_Data_Career_Meeting_Rating?

Comment: They are not tables, they are views

Comment: You didn't tell me the datatypes, I'm trying to figure out what you are actually trying to do. Are you creating some sort of pivot table? Why does this code need to work?

Comment: It is sort of like a pivot table. I am trying to each table to produce one column. IE Meeting or Manager ratings for different years.

Comment: We need the datatypes for the fields